# Updating lines in a file

Tags: java

I never worked with files before, but what I am trying to accomplish is be able to get and set data.

I already have a way to get the data, and it works fine. (It may not be the best way either)
I also have a way to set data. But the problem is when I set the data, not only does it work, but the data also duplicates itself.

Here are my variables:

```
private File file;
private FileReader fr;
private BufferedReader reader;
private Formatter f;

private Map<String, String> dataList = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
private List<String> itemList;
```

This is what I use to retrieve the data:

```
public void getData() {
    String line = null;
    openFileReader();
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        while((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        String[] items = sb.toString().split("\n");
        itemList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
        for(String item : itemList) {
            String[] itemData = item.split(":");
            if(!(buffReader.readLine() == null)) {
                dataList.put(itemData[0], itemData[1]);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    closeFileReader();
}
```

Heres what I use to set the data:

My method was to get and store the data in a arraylist/hashmap, delete the file, create the file, remove the line I don't want, then set all the data into the file.

```
public void set(String section, String data) {
    openFileWriter();

    if(hasKey(section)) {
        file.delete();
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dataList.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();

            //I don't think this block actually works...
            String beforeStringOfData = key + ":" + value;
            dataList.remove(section);
            if(itemList.contains(beforeStringOfData)) {
                itemList.remove(beforeStringOfData);
            }

            String finalStringOfData = section + ":" + data;
            itemList.add(finalStringOfData);
            dataList.put(section, data);
            for(String items : itemList) {
                f.format("%s%n", items);
            }
        }
    } else {
        dataList.put(section, data);
        String finalStringOfData = section + ":" + data;
        itemList.add(finalStringOfData);
        for(String i: itemList) {
            f.format("%s%n", i);
        }
    }

    closeFileWriter();
}

private boolean hasKey(String key) {
    if(dataList.containsKey(key))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I'm not asking for a whole re-write of my code. Just a little hint or tip on how I should go about fixing my problem.

All help is well appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code has a lot of errors, the "dataList" `Map` won't contain any entries because of this statement `if(!(buffReader.readLine() == null))`, this condition will always be `false` because at this point in the code you've already read all the lines from the file.

Comment: Also you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException` in the `set(...)` method when you try to remove an item from the "itemList" `Map`

Comment: @Titus So do you think I should read the file the same time I set something to the file, instead of reading the file once?

Comment: What I'm saying is that before you enter the second loop (the `for` loop) you've already read all the data from the file and stored it in the "itemList" `ArrayList` at this point you can close the "buffReader".